# How to access foreach loop variable in php?

Tags: php, joomla, facebook-opengraph

There is the following code that works correctly, that is, the title of the post is displayed and after the comma its category name on the page in the header:

```
 <?php foreach (HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi) as $category) { echo $category['name'];}?></h1>
```

How can I display a post with the same title, category ['name'] format in OpenGraph?

The following working code but no category name:

`<meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.'" />`

How can I correctly add the category name after the title, separated by commas? This part of code: `<?php foreach (HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi) as $category) { echo $category['name'];}?>`

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
 echo $mySobi->title.' , '.$category;
```

***Apply it like this***

```
$YouTitle = "MY TITLE";
$category = "MY CATEGORY";
$Meta = $YouTitle." , ".$category;

echo'<meta property="og:title" content="'.$Meta.'" />';
```

***Or from an array***

```
$source = array(
    "Title" => "My Title",
    "category" => "My Category"
    );

$meta = $source['Title']." , ".$source['category'];

echo'<meta property="og:title" content="'.$meta.'" />';
```

Comment: The following working code but no category name: `<meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.'" />` where to insert your solution?

Comment: How can I understand if I don't know where your category is from and what source your title is from?, you have to enter a script of where the category comes from

Comment: `Apply it like this` works super! however, how to call the category name? `$category = "MY CATEGORY"; ` `$category = "<?php foreach (HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi) as $category) { echo $category['name'];}?>"; ` ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question properly, this might be what you want:

```php
$categories = array_map(function($category) {
    return $category['name'];
}, HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi));
$opengraph_meta=' <meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.' '.implode(', ', $categories).'" />';
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected `<`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I wrapped it in an echo

Comment: My complete code : `$opengraph_meta='
<meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.'" />';`

Comment: Okay, I added your code to the answer

Comment: Why, when using this when further on the page, `<?php echo $categories; ?>` there is no output of the category name, but the value is shown instead `ARRAY`>?

Comment: Because it is an associative array. It has multiple categories with probably more fields than just the `name` in each category. And since an array is a [compound type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php), it cannot be directly `echo`d as string.

Comment: Where should you put a space between the name and the category? `<meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.implode(', ', $categories).'" />`

Comment: before `implode` like this: `<meta property="og:title" content="'.$mySobi->title.' '.implode(', ', $categories).'" />`

Comment: Are there any medots for referring to $categories other than the `implode`? To use `$categories` further down the page instead of `<?php foreach (HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi) as $category) { echo $category['name'];}?>` ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to output this array as a string, there has to be some sort of "stringification" so I concatinated them with a comma. If you want to use them without outputting them, using $categories is of course fine.

Comment: Maybe there is a more beautiful solution than mine `<h1><?php echo $mySobi->title; ?>,
        <?php foreach (HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi) as $category) { echo $category['name'];}?></h1>` , considering that I now have a variable `$categories`

Comment: Yes, mine. Just use the same code that is used for the meta tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how to do it correctly?

Comment: `<h1><?php echo $mySobi->title; ?>, <?php echo implode(', ', $categories); ?></h1>`